# How to create GRange object for a large dataset

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a large dataset with colnames:

```
    "chromosome"      "start"         "end"         "h.gene"        "CPCN_LUNG"     "NCIH524_LUNG"  "SBC5_LUNG"     "NCIH446_LUNG"  "NCIH196_LUNG" 
  "NCIH209_LUNG"  "NCIH1963_LUNG" "NCIH211_LUNG"  "NCIH2196_LUNG" "NCIH526_LUNG"  "NCIH82_LUNG"   "SW1271_LUNG"   "DMS114_LUNG"   "NCIH2029_LUNG" "NCIH2066_LUNG" "NCIH1341_LUNG"
  "NCIH2227_LUNG" "NCIH69_LUNG"   "NCIH1048_LUNG" "DMS53_LUNG"    "SHP77_LUNG"    "NCIH1836_LUNG" "NCIH2141_LUNG" "COLO668_LUNG"  "NCIH1105_LUNG" "NCIH1876_LUNG" "NCIH841_LUNG" 
 "DMS273_LUNG"   "CORL279_LUNG"  "NCIH1092_LUNG" "CORL95_LUNG"   "CORL88_LUNG"   "NCIH1694_LUNG" "NCIH1436_LUNG"
```

I want to create GRange object on this dataset.

```
reference_GRange <- GRanges(seqnames= reference$chromosome,IRanges(start= reference$start,end= reference$end),h.gene=reference$h.gene)
```

This will create Grange object with only 2 meta data column. Is there any way to create Grange object with all the information in reference table. [for e.g. with meta data column from h.gene,CPCN_LUNG, NCIH524_LUNG,......... to NCIH1436_LUNG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `makeGRangesFromDataFrame()` with `keep.extra.columns=TRUE`. Alternatively create the `GRanges` as above, then add `mcols()` dropping uninteresting columns.

```
mcols(gr) = reference[,-(1:3)]
```

Feel free to ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Answer (score 0):

reference_GRange <- GRanges(seqnames= reference$chromosome,IRanges(start= reference$start,end= reference$end),h.gene=reference$h.gene, CPCN_LUNG =  reference$CPCN_LUNG, NCIH524_LUNG = reference$NCIH524_LUNG,..... NCIH1436_LUNG= reference$NCIH1436_LUNG).

But have add each additional columns manually in the GRnage object, which may be hazzle job!!!

Comment: i am aware of that..I am asking for any easy way to include the additional columns in to the Grange object